# SSLHandshakeException while calling webservice through volley library

Tags: android, ssl, android-volley, sslhandshakeexception

I am getting this exception

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification 
path not found.
```

from volley while accessing web service in some devices. I have searched a lot, but certificate of SSL is properly inserted in server side. Is there anything else to do in android side?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share your code what you have done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043324/android-volley-error-trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found-only-in-r

Comment: thanks for your reply abhinav, same issue is am facing, i have did that Trust manager already, but while uploading into google play, i am getting security error. 
Is there any other solution to solve by android side?

Comment: Is there any way to setSSLSocketFactory to volley library ?