# Unexpected response code 303 Volley error

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley

I'm using this Volley version `implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'` in my project and it works fine, but today I found it didn't got the response from the server with this error code:

> E/Volley: [4722] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 303 for http://....other_link_part

When I click on the link, I find it working fine and the json appears successfully to me on the browser.

Comment: Please implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'. Code 303 is a way to redirect web applications to a new URI

Comment: I do that implementation but the problem stills the same, I also read in https://github.com/samkirton/android-volley version 1.0.19 just handles 301 or 302 redirects so is there any other way to handle 303 redirect?

Answer (score 1):

I got problem like that when I handled switching from https to http manually when my link was https has problem with certificate

com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not foundو so it appears disconnected in check connection with the server and the link schema changes to http which gives me 303 error code when I find https certificate error and solve like this link :
[Android volley error: "Trust anchor for certification path not found", only in real device, not emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043324/android-volley-error-trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found-only-in-r)   everything works fine.

so my suggestion 
- be ensure your are connected with the right link schema of the server if it
 (http or https)
- check volley error message
- if it's a problem with the certificate try to solve it first

hope that can solve your problem