# Retrofit ssl=0x717f870208: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

Tags: android, android-studio, ssl-certificate, retrofit

My code was working fine and I received data from the server but suddenly I got this error : 
`javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x717c368708: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer`

also sometimes I got this error :

```
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: 
Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

I'm using retrofit

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
```

and here is the init for it

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl).
                addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
 Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
 Call<ProfileResult> profileCallBack = api.getProfileData();
```

Comment: `Connection reset by peer` sounds like the server closed the connection on you. Your question does not include enough information to even guess at why. `MalformedJsonException` sounds like it sent you some bad json. Once again, your question does not include enough information.

Comment: I found the problem was in my ISP which redirects me to their website for displaying a message about internet consumption and stuck in that redirect, when I run the application using data or different WiFi it works fine! @greeble31

Comment: @greeble31 do you think a handshake between me (user) and the server was established before this error happened? I'm trying everything I find on stackoverflow to solve my problem (```CertPathValidatorException : Trust anchor for certificate path not found```) and now I receive this error (```javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x717c368708: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer```) and I can't figure it out if I made it worse or solved a part of my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @AndreiManolache Debugging SSL problems can be quite involved, if the answers presently on SO don't work for you, you should post a new question for your specific circumstances. That's sure to get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @AndreiManolache also check this question too it may help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55992416/java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexception-trust-anchor-for-certification-pa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was in my ISP which redirects me to their website for displaying a message about internet consumption and stuck in that redirect, when I run the application using data or different WiFi it works fine!